# Facebook: Invite to application without using Facebook's dialogue box

Tags: facebook

I have made a custom invite screen in my Flash application, when the send button is clicked I want all the selected facebook Ids to be sent, ideally without a dialogue window popping up.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

User to user app requests must use the requests dialog
App to user requests can be sent via the app access token but can only be sent to existing app users and are not displayed the same way on Facebook.com

You can specify an `ids` parameter to the requests dialog when firing it to show only the users selected earlier in the workflow if you wish